# How to show a message box for a specified time?

Tags: inno-setup, messagebox

Is there a way to show a message box for a specified time (that means, the message box will close itself when the specified time elapses) ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Windows API has a function for showing a message box for a specified time, but for some reason is that function undocumented, which means it is not officially supported and may well be subject to change.

That function is called `MessageBoxTimeout`, and it has even export in the `user32.dll` library, what makes me feel that the only thing this function lacks is the official documentation. But who knows...

The following script shows how to display a message box for 5 seconds before the wizard form is shown. If the user doesn't click the OK button, nor manually close the window, the message box is automatically closed when that 5 seconds period elapses:

```pascal
[Code]
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif
const
  MB_TIMEDOUT = 32000;
  MB_ICONERROR = $10;
  MB_ICONQUESTION = $20;
  MB_ICONWARNING = $30;
  MB_ICONINFORMATION = $40;

function MessageBoxTimeout(hWnd: HWND; lpText: string; lpCaption: string;
  uType: UINT; wLanguageId: Word; dwMilliseconds: DWORD): Integer;
  external 'MessageBoxTimeout{#AW}@user32.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  MessageBoxTimeout(WizardForm.Handle, 'This message will be automatically ' +
    'closed in 5 seconds!', 'Caption...', MB_OK or MB_ICONINFORMATION, 0, 5000);
end;
```

For more information about parameters and result values refer to the [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function help site and some of the unofficial articles describing the `MessageBoxTimeout` function itself, like e.g.:

- [Maurizio Pisano: MessageBoxTimeout API (CodeProject)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7914/MessageBoxTimeout-API)
- [Eddie Shipman: Undocumented MessageBoxTimeOut function (Embarcadero)](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32736)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more customized implementation than the `MessageBoxTimeout` from [@TLama's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20816881/850848#20816882) allows (like countdown display or custom button captions):

- create a custom form using [`CreateCustomForm`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcustomform);
- use [`SetTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer) to implement the timeout/count down.

For a complete code, see [MsgBox - Make unclickable OK Button and change to countdown - Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40446269/850848).