# MsgBox - Make unclickable OK Button and change to countdown - Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How to change OK button into a countdown timer like this...

- 5,4,3,2,1,0 [MsgBox Closes automatically] don't display 0
- Proceeds to setup procedure.

The button should not be clickable and faded. Like inactive window/button/box.

this one:

[image: this one]

not this one:

[image: not this one]

I use the code code from this question: [How to show a message box for a specified time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816881/how-to-show-a-message-box-for-a-specified-time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in function with such functionality. Neither in Inno Setup, nor WinAPI.

You have to implement the dialog on your own and use a timer to implement the count down.

```pascal
[Code]

function SetTimer(hWnd: LongWord; nIDEvent, uElapse: LongWord; 
  lpTimerFunc: LongWord): LongWord; external 'SetTimer@user32.dll stdcall';
function KillTimer(hWnd: HWND; uIDEvent: LongWord): BOOL;
  external 'KillTimer@user32.dll stdcall';

var
  CountdownButton: TNewButton;
  Countdown: Integer;

procedure UpdateCountDownButtonCaption;
begin
  CountdownButton.Caption := Format('%d sec', [Countdown]);
end;

procedure CountdownProc(
  H: LongWord; Msg: LongWord; IdEvent: LongWord; Time: LongWord);
begin
  Dec(Countdown);
  if Countdown = 0 then
  begin
    CountdownButton.Enabled := True;
    TForm(CountdownButton.Parent).Close;
  end
    else
  begin
    UpdateCountDownButtonCaption;
  end;
end;

procedure CountdownMessageBoxCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  { Prevent the dialog from being close by the X button and Alt-F4 }
  CanClose := CountdownButton.Enabled;
end;

procedure CountdownMessageBox(Message: string; Seconds: Integer);
var
  Form: TSetupForm;
  MessageLabel: TLabel;
  Timer: LongWord;
begin
  Form := CreateCustomForm;
  try
    Form.ClientWidth := ScaleX(256);
    Form.ClientHeight := ScaleY(96);
    Form.Caption := 'Information';
    Form.Position := poMainFormCenter;
    Form.OnCloseQuery := @CountdownMessageBoxCloseQuery;

    MessageLabel := TLabel.Create(Form);
    MessageLabel.Top := ScaleY(16);
    MessageLabel.Left := ScaleX(16);
    MessageLabel.AutoSize := True;
    MessageLabel.Caption := Message;
    MessageLabel.Parent := Form;

    if CountdownButton <> nil then
      RaiseException('Countdown in progress already');

    Countdown := Seconds;

    CountdownButton := TNewButton.Create(Form);
    CountdownButton.Parent := Form;
    CountdownButton.Width := ScaleX(88);
    CountdownButton.Height := ScaleY(26);
    CountdownButton.Left :=
      Form.ClientWidth - CountdownButton.Width - ScaleX(18);
    CountdownButton.Top :=
      Form.ClientHeight - CountdownButton.Height - ScaleX(11);
    UpdateCountDownButtonCaption;
    CountdownButton.Name := 'CountdownButton';
    CountdownButton.ModalResult := mrOk;
    CountdownButton.Default := True;
    CountdownButton.Enabled := False;

    Timer := SetTimer(0, 0, 1000, CreateCallback(@CountdownProc));

    try
      Form.ShowModal();
    finally
      KillTimer(0, Timer);
    end;
  finally
    Form.Free();
    CountdownButton := nil;
  end;
end;
```

*For [`CreateCallback` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcallback), you need Inno Setup 6. If you are stuck with Inno Setup 5, you can use `WrapCallback` function from [InnoTools InnoCallback](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=54) library.*

---

Use it like:

```pascal
CountdownMessageBox('Message here', 10);
```

---

[image: Countdown dialog]

---

Related questions:

- [How to show a message box for a specified time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20816881/850848)
- [Inno Setup - How to close finished installer after a certain time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42391190/850848)
- [Inno Setup - Automatically submitting uninstall prompts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42259914/850848).