# Image on a splash screen before Inno Setup installer does not display

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to create a splash screen for my installer in Inno Setup.
I create a form that is displayed for 2 seconds at the beginning of the installer, but the image is not displayed in it.

Only when I use the `ShowModal` function is it displayed, but it does not close after 2 seconds.

Here is my code:

```pascal
[Code]
var
SplashForm: TSetupForm;
BIRegistry: TBitmapImage;

procedure SplashScreen;
begin
  SplashForm := CreateCustomForm;
  SplashForm.Position := poScreenCenter;
  SplashForm.BorderStyle := bsNone;  
  BIRegistry := TBitmapImage.Create(SplashForm);
  BIRegistry.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\regtoexe.bmp'));
  BIRegistry.Parent := SplashForm;
  BIRegistry.AutoSize := True;
  SplashForm.ClientHeight := BIRegistry.Height;
  SplashForm.ClientWidth := BIRegistry.Width;
  SplashForm.Show;
  Sleep(2000);
  SplashForm.Close;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('regtoexe.bmp');

  SplashScreen;
```

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because by calling `Sleep` you freeze Windows message pump, so the image cannot draw.

---

Quick and dirty solution is to force repaint before the `Sleep`:

```pascal
SplashForm.Show;
SplashForm.Repaint;
Sleep(2000);
SplashForm.Close;
```

*This is what Inno Setup Script Includes (ISSI) package was doing.*

---

More correct way is to use the `ShowModal` and have the modal window close automatically after specified time:

```pascal
var
  CloseSplashTimer: LongWord;

function SetTimer(hWnd, nIDEvent, uElapse, lpTimerFunc: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'SetTimer@User32.dll stdcall';
function KillTimer(hWnd, nIDEvent: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'KillTimer@User32.dll stdcall';

procedure CloseSplashProc(
  H: LongWord; Msg: LongWord; IdEvent: LongWord; Time: LongWord);
begin
  KillTimer(0, CloseSplashTimer);
  SplashForm.Close;
end;

procedure SplashScreen;
begin
  SplashForm := CreateCustomForm;
  // rest of your splash window setup code

  CloseSplashTimer := SetTimer(0, 0, 2000, CreateCallback(@CloseSplashProc));
  SplashForm.ShowModal;
end;
```

Based on: [MsgBox - Make unclickable OK Button and change to countdown - Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40446269/850848)